# Magento 2.1 Upgrade Data Issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, cli

Following directions from Magento Documentation for Command-line upgrade to Magento 2.1. Running into some errors when data is upgrading. Below are the errors i receive after running the upgrade command.

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-Images' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRI  
  BUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME', query was: UPDATE `eav_attribute_group` SET `attribute_group_name` = ? WHERE (`a  
  ttribute_group_id`=10)  

  [PDOException]                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-Images' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRI  
  BUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME'
```

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Did you attempt to install this more than once?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to a migration from Magento 1.9. Just go to `eav_attribute_group`, delete the row with `images` in `attribute_group_name` and re-run upgrade.